# Adding custom URL schema in phonegap iOS project

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using phonegap 1.4 for my iOS projects. I am trying to open my app from the other app using custom url schema. I added the following keys in .plist file:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.cams.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <string>myApp</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

After doing the modification i added `<a href="myApp://">Open myApp</a>` in my other app and tried to open the myapp. But when i clicked on "Open myApp" nothing happens.

Does phonegap supports custom url schema or i am doing something wrong. Plz help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My custom URL is in an array.  Here is a sample:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.cams.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

You should use the Property editor to edit this file and get the format correct.

[image]